# How do i get servlet instance from web.xml in my java class

Tags: java, servlets

I have following entry in my `web.xml` and I need instance of that class in my java file
how do I do that?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DummyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.Xxxx</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: could you be more precise? What do you mean by "instance of that class in my java file"?

Comment: This makes no utter sense. Whatever you think to solve with this approach should definitely be solved differently. [Try asking a question about the real problem instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4073013/1530938

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion may be i need to use different approach..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally do not, the servlet container is responsible for instantiating a single Servlet instance for every servlet element in the web.xml and to use these to process requests and generate responses.

Otherwise, you probably need to parse the web.xml and get the servlet class using Class.forName(className) and then create an instance using clazz.newInstance() assming a default constructor exists (which it should, since this is a servlet).

Comment: that will create new servlet dude not give the old one

Answer (score 1):

Currently I don't believe you can as the servlet container creates a single instance of any given servlets and spawns threads to cater for requests. It simply isn't in your interest to gain access to that one instance that is also being used by the container

There is also the (now deprecated) `ServletContext.getServlet("yourClassName")`. But don't do it
I'm struggling to imagine under what circumstances you'll need to control a servlet instance that DI and good design can't help you avoid. What is the concrete problem?

Comment: for instance for me the problem is that i need to access servlet before filterChain is all used in a first filter